# Pull latest version of content for all languages in a revisions system

Tags: php, mysql, version-control, localization, internationalization

I have a MySQL database which has three database tables: `news_articles`, `languages` and `news_articles_languages`.

- The `languages` table holds a record for each language the system supports
- The `news_articles` table holds generic information on a news article, such as ID and an attached image
- The `news_articles_languages` table contains localized information on a news article, and also stores revisions.

The structure of the `news_articles_languages` table is as follows:

```
id            INT       AUTO_INCREMENT
article_id    INT
language_id   INT
title         VARCHAR
friendly_name VARCHAR
content       TEXT
created       TIMESTAMP
```

When a news article is saved, the translations are inserted into this table with a new `created` column, so I can easily query previous revisions.

However, I want to be able to pull out all **latest** revisions based on an article ID. What would the query for this be? I've tried various combinations of `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`, but these only give one result in one language; I want **all** languages for a given article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the revision with the highest id is always the latest, then the following should work I think.  If you can't depend on that and need to use 'created', then I'm not sure!

```
SELECT * FROM `news_articles_languages` WHERE id IN(SELECT MAX(id) FROM `news_articles_languages` WHERE article_id = 1 GROUP BY language_id)
```

Comment: Yeah, the highest ID *should* be the latest, but you can never be too sure! I've had funny things happen to MySQL tables with `auto_increment` columns in the past...